# How to extract every line in a file and split at blank space using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, node.js, file-handling

Currently I have this in `htmlcss.txt`

```
a.html 1.css
b.html 2.css
c.html 3.css
d.html 4.css
e.html 5.css
```

How do I extract every line in this file and split at the blank space so that my array consists of 
`[a.html, 1.css]`---->first iteration
`[b.html, 2.css]`---->second iteration
...and so on
For use in this code:

```
            var i = 0;

            for ( i=0; i<5; i++ ) { //there are 5 lines in my file

            var arr; //array of length 2
                     //how to create this array so that it contains the aforementioned data?

            var n=arr[0];
            var m=arr[1];

             //Some tasks with m and n
            }
```

I have searched a lot and this is probably a stupid question, but I have spent quite a bit of time already with no luck yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you accessing the content of htmlcss.txt? Is this using nodejs, or designed to work client side with AJAX?

Comment: Exactly, I am modifying my Gruntfile.js and htmlcss.txt was created by me.

Answer (score 0):

To read a file you may use NodeJS' `readFile()` that will put it into a string.

Note that `readFile()` operates asyncronously. So it doesn't stop, read the file then proceed. Instead it start reading the file the proceeds with the next statement. In order to process the file you must place this functionality inside a callback that's provided as parameter to `readFile()`

See https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-read-files-in-nodejs

Then you may use `split()` method that applies to strings to do subsequent tasks.

First split the file by line feeds `\n` (assuming unix linefeeds)

Then split by spaces.

```
fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('htmlcss.txt', 'utf8', function (err,str) {

    var lines,      // array: 1 item for every line
        count,      // how many lines
        i,        
        arr,        // array: 1 item for every space-separated item
        m,          
        n;

    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    lines = str.split("\n");

    count = lines.lenght; // are you sure the lines are 5 ? Let's get it at runtime. 

    for ( i=0; i<count; i++ ) { //there are 5 lines in my file

        arr = lines[i].split(" ");
        n=arr[0];
        m=arr[1];

        // Some tasks with m and n
    }

});
```

I've put variable decalaration at the beginning for better readability.

Comment: "let's assume htmlcss.txt is stored into str ", could you please tell me by code how to store htmlcss.txt into str?

Comment: that deserves a different question: "how to store a file into a string" - You're asking how to split the string...

Comment: My question also asks how to extract every line.